# Moduli space of null Sasaki $η$-Einstein structures for higher dimensions(Calabi-Yau structures in Sasakian setting)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, kahler-manifolds, sasakian-geometry

[The moduli space of null Sasaki $η$-Einstein structures](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10711-013-9859-9#page-1) for simply connected compact 5-dimensional manifold $M$ is determined by the following quadric

$$\{[\alpha]\in H^2(M,\mathbb C) \; \text{such that} \; |([\alpha],[\alpha])|+|([\alpha],[\bar\alpha])|>0\}/\mathbb C^*$$

> Is there any explicit moduli space of null Sasaki $η$-Einstein
>   structures for higher dimensions?